# EJS template (NodeJS + express) converts decimal to integer

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

When I pass the data dictionary to the EJS template, it formats the decimals as integers.  What's the recommended way to fix it?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    let data = {
        lat: 42.0,
        lng: 78.0
    }
    res.render('pages/index',data);
    });

app.listen(8080);
```

The index.ejs template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
test <%= lat %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are no decimals and integers in JS - it has a single numeric type which is an IEEE 754 floating point number. When displaying a numeric values, any excess zeroes from the decimal representation are dropped: e.g. `3.50` -> `3.5` and `4.00` -> `4`. If you want show a numeric value with a specific format, you have to do it as a string.

Comment: I want to do formatting in the template.  I don't want to format the numbers in code.

Comment: OK, then format them normally. There is no concept in JS for a *numeric value* having a format. `4.0 === 4` and `4.00000000 === 4`, they all use the same representation, so JS simply shows you the shortest it can. You never "lose" the decimal zeroes - they simply never existed in the numeric representation. If you need to format `4.0` to anything, then you'd need to do it with `4` anyway.

Comment: You can use toFixed to get a string representation with trailing zeros: `(42.0).toFixed(1); // "42.0"`

Comment: I'm so used to other templating engines that I didn't think about the central tenet of EJS is that the template itself is JS.

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

```
test <%= lat.toPrecision(8) %>
```